# Python CSV with history data and future data - Need to Group by and Calculate values

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by

I have a 5 column csv file that includes past data and future data(July data). I need to use python to group each row based on **ITEM**. You can see in my data there's two items, 6200000 and 6200001. I want to make a calculation for future data ATP based on mean/stdev of the past data for each item.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0RiJ.png)

below is my current code but it can only apply to 1 item not multiple items because the calculation result is wrong, I wonder do I need to create a dictionary first. I'm new to python any help will be appreciated.

```
total_data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
present_data = total_data.dropna()
future_data=total_data[total_data['Actual Quantity'].isna()]  #I divided data by historical data and future data

present_data['Z'] = present_data['Actual Quantity'] / present_data['Scheduled Quantity']
present_data['logZ'] = np.log(present_data['Z'])
present_data['logX'] = np.log(present_data['Grade Yields']) #add 3 columns for calculation


sched = future_data.groupby('Item').Sched_Quantity.agg([('Sched_Quantity', ','.join)]).reset_index()

#Calculations

ProjectedProduction_list = []
atp_list = []
holdback_list =[]
PercentAtp_list = []

for i in present_data["Item.[Item]"].unique():

# print('For Item ID: '+ str(i))
datatemp = present_data[present_data['Item.[Item]'] == i]

string_item = str(i)


x = sched['Sched_Quantity'][sched.Item ==string_item ].tolist()

#Required y values  

y_list = x[0].split(',')
# logger.debug('y_list : {}'.format(y_list))
y_list = [int(float(i)) for i in y_list]

 

for y in y_list:      #loop for calculation
   
    mean1 = datatemp["Grade Yields"].mean()
    mean2 = datatemp["logZ"].mean()
    var1 = datatemp["logX"].var()
    var2 = datatemp["logZ"].var()
    ProjectedProduction = datatemp["Grade Yields"].mean() * y 
    ProjectedProduction_list.append(ProjectedProduction)
    CI = confidencelevel['Confidence Level']
    OutputAtp = mean1 * y * math.exp(mean2 - (norm.ppf(CI) * (math.sqrt(var1 + var2))))
    atp_list.append(OutputAtp)
    Holdback = ProjectedProduction - OutputAtp
    holdback_list.append(Holdback)
    PercentAtp = (OutputAtp/ProjectedProduction) * 100
    PercentAtp_list.append(PercentAtp)

 
future_data['ProjectedProduction'] = ProjectedProduction_list
future_data['OutputAtp'] = atp_list
future_data['Holdback'] = holdback_list
future_data['PercentAtp'] = PercentAtp_list
```

Current outcome: the items are mix together so the outcome of ATP is not correct. I want the calculation is based on each item, but my current code mixed 2 items together.
[Outcome of Future Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEQsO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out the documentation and examples for `DataFrame.groupby()`, it can be used to apply a function to groups of rows, based on a common value of a column.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html